# Query string hiding

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to remove the query string from the url.

```
For eg: localhost/index.php?page=value to localhost/index.php
```

I am currently using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

It is not **rewriting** ...
Is anything i am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Removed QSL as commented by **Clive**

Comment: QSA stands for Query String Append...

Comment: The query string part of the URL can't be rewritten, it will be added to the new query string of the rewritten URL whatever you do. URL rewriting is meant to work the other way round.

Comment: @Alasdair: that's only partially true, if you make the rewrite end in `?` it should drop the query string. See this blog post for more information: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/

Comment: Please explain more about the purpose and goal of this.

Comment: @deceze i had given an example in description for what i am looking...

Comment: How is it supposed to know which page is being requested?

Comment: You're just saying you want to "remove the query string", you don't say in what situation or what for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we're rewriting the original request to itself with an empty query string if the query string is not empty.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?
```

This is already included in Apache though with `[QSD] Query String Discard`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [QSD]
```

***Note:*** Query strings allow you to track all sorts of things in log files and in links from outside sources. Doing this will limit those options.

That's likely not what you want to do (lose a lot of old links for SEO that way). So, here's how to redirect old query strings to new URLs as a 301 redirect. This gets a little visually confusing to people not familiar with RegEx or how Apache works. Ending with a question mark in the first part of the string means "maybe the preceeding character." In this instance we've appended the `?` at the end of the replacement (not a REGEX pattern) because Apache's default behavior is similar to `[QSA]` (query string append) according to the [Apache manual for the QSD flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd). So the addition of the single `?` by itself is creating an empty query string to nullify the existing string. There are a couple of answers on StackOverflow that use this method.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.*)
RewriteRule .* %1/? [R=301,L]
```

Using `[QSD]` you could write it this way:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.*)
RewriteRule .* %1/ [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Your other match takes a file like `contact.php` and redirects it to `/contact/`. Which may also still be valid.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1/? [R=301,L]
```

This rule could also be written with QSD:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L,QSD]
```